# How to exit a VBA macro when the form's "X" button is clicked?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro that pops up a form when someone sends an email and asks them to select a classification. Under ThisOutlookSession I have:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

          Dim frm As classificationForm
          Dim chosenvalue As String

          Set frm = New classificationForm
          frm.Show vbModal

          Select Case True
          Case frm.restrictedButton.Value
            chosenvalue = "Restricted"
          Case frm.internalButton.Value
            chosenvalue = "Internal"
          Case frm.publicButton.Value
            chosenvalue = "Public"
          Case Else
            MsgBox "No classification chosen"
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
          End Select

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
      Item.Subject = "[" & chosenvalue & "] " & Item.Subject
    End If

End Sub
```

and under classificationForm I have:

```
Private Sub okCommand_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cancelCommand_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

The form is 3 option buttons (the classifications) and 2 command buttons (OK and Cancel).

The [Internal] option button is selected by default. However, if someone clicks the form's "X" button in the top-right corner or the "Cancel" command button, then the Macro sends the email with the selected classification button when I want it to kick me back to the draft email like it would if there were no options selected.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @drunken squirrel - `macros` is not a tag for VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Unload` is a lie. It seems to only work with the form's *default instance*, and working with forms' default instance is a poisonous place you don't want to go.

Don't unload. `Hide` instead.

Another problem is that since the calling code is querying the form's controls' state, it doesn't matter how the form was closed: Ok, Cancel, "X" - everything single one of these buttons gets the form unloaded and whatever was selected is acted upon: you have no mechanism in place to determine whether the user okayed the dialog, or wishes to cancel everything.

Add a `Cancelled` property:

```
Private IsCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = IsCancelled
End Property
```

Handle the `QueryClose` event, set the `Cancel` parameter to `False` when the `CloseMode` is `vbFormControlMenu`, and `Hide` the form - actually, what you want is for that "X" button to do exactly the same thing as your *Cancel* button, so just do that:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    IsCancelled = True
    Me.Hide        
End Sub
```

Now your calling code can determine whether the form was cancelled, and act accordingly.

```
If frm.Cancelled Then
    Cancel = True
Else
    'user okayed the dialog: determine the selection...
End If
```

See [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for more in-depth information about user forms: the calling code doesn't *need* to care about the controls on the form.

Answer (score 0):

use `UserForm_QueryClose()` event handler to intercept any userform red "X" clicking

then change your `UserForm` code pane as follows:

```
Private Sub okCommand_Click()
    Me.Hide ' don't unload the Form, just hide it
End Sub

Private Sub cancelCommand_Click()
    Me.Tag = "NO" ' signal to the calling sub that it must not send the email
    Me.Hide ' don't unload the Form, just hide it
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then Me.Tag = "NO" ' if user clicked the red X button signal to the calling sub that it must not send the email
End Sub
```

and adjust your `Application_ItemSend` event handler code accordingly:

```
Set frm = New classificationForm
With frm
    .Show vbModal
    If .Tag <> "NO" Then ' if userform didn't signal not to send the email 
        Select Case True
            Case frm.restrictedButton.Value
                chosenvalue = "Restricted"
            Case frm.internalButton.Value
                chosenvalue = "Internal"
            Case frm.publicButton.Value
                chosenvalue = "Public"
            Case Else
                MsgBox "No classification chosen"
                Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    Else ' the userform signaled not to send the email
        MsgBox "No classification chosen"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End With
Unload frm
```

Comment: Unconditionally setting the tag value in `QueryClose` will not set the tag *only* when the "X" button is clicked, as hinted by the `CloseMode` value. Also, `Unload frm` is redundant, and if you had `With New classificationForm` then you wouldn't even need the `frm` variable, and it would be dead & burried at `End With`. Clever use of the form's `Tag`, although I prefer using a `Boolean` custom property rather than magic strings. A Boolean property also makes the condition test for a positive, which reads better.

Comment: edited and inserted the check for setting the tag only when the "X" button is clicked. thanks @MathieuGuindon. Why is `Unload frm` redundant? And isn't the `With Userform1 .. End With` a bad practice?

Comment: I never said `With UserForm1`, I said `With New`, a construct which makes the `With` block hold the object reference for the new instance of the form class, making the object's lifetime entirely constrained by the `With` block. Working against the default instance of a form is a practice I've been actively fighting for quite some time now ;-)

Comment: Great, almost all work except for the X button. When clicked it gives the error:

Run-time error '-2147418105 (80010007)': Automation error. The callee (server [not server application]) is not available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may have executed.

The Debug highlights the line "If .Tag <> "NO" Then...."

Comment: Have you changed “okCommand_Click()” and “cancelCommand_Click()” as per my answer?